# elements in group $\frac{G/[G,G]}{[G,G]N/[G,G]}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a free group generated by $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$,$[G,G]$ denote the subgroup of $G$ generated by commutators $\{aba^{-1}b^{-1}\mid a,b\in G\}$

hence we know $G/[G,G]$ is a free abelian group, generated by $\overline{a_1},...,\overline{a_n}$ (where $\overline{a}_i $ is image under the canonical projection $\pi:G\to G/[G,G]$ ).

assume normal subgroup $N\subset G$ is the least normal subgroup containing the element $\{a_1^2a^2_2...a_n^2\}$.where $[G,G]N$ denote the subgroup $\{an\mid a\in [G,G],n\in N\}\subset G$

Now we want to study what $\frac{G/[G,G]}{[G,G]N/[G,G]}$ is,here gives the result ,letting $G' = $ free abelian group generated by  $\overline{a_1},...,\overline{a_n}$

hence we have :

$$\frac{G/[G,G]}{[G,G]N/[G,G]} = G'/\left<\overline{a_1}^2\overline{a_2}^2...\overline{a_n}^2\right> \tag{*}$$

I have no idea how to get (*),the point is why $\left<\overline{a_1}^2\overline{a_2}^2...\overline{a_n}^2\right> = [G,G]N/[G,G]$

I can do as follows since $ \pi(a_1^2a_2^2...a_n^2)\subset \pi(N) =[G,G]N/[G,G] $

We have $\left<\overline{a_1}^2\overline{a_2}^2...\overline{a_n}^2\right> \subset[G,G]N/[G,G]$

Second $N$ is least normal subgroup of $\{a_1^2a^2_2...a_n^2\}$ by surjective of $\pi$ we have $\pi(N)$ is the least normal subgroup of $\overline{a_1}^2\overline{a_2}^2...\overline{a_n}^2$ since if exist another normal subgroup $K\subset G/[G,G]$ containing $\overline{a_1}^2\overline{a_2}^2...\overline{a_n}^2$ we have $\pi(N) \subset \pi(\pi^{-1}(K))\subset K$ which means $\pi(N)$ is the least normal one,but $\left<\overline{a_1}^2\overline{a_2}^2...\overline{a_n}^2\right>$ itself is normal we have $\pi(N) = \left<\overline{a_1}^2\overline{a_2}^2...\overline{a_n}^2\right>$

Comment: The isomorphism theorems tell you that if $H\leq K\leq G$, $H\triangleleft G$, and $K\triangleleft G$, then $K/H\triangleleft G/H$ and $(G/H)/(K/H)\cong G/K$. That’s what you have here, with $H=[G,G]$, and $K=[G,G]N$. So the group you are trying to figure out is $G/[G,G]N$. $[G,G]N$ is the smallest normal subgroup that contains **both** all commutators and $N$. But this is the same as the subgroup generated by $[G,G]$ and $a_1^2,\ldots,a_n^2$, since any subgroup that contains $[G,G]$ is normal. So you can replace $[G,G]N$ with $\langle [G,G],a_1^2,\ldots,a_n^2\rangle$.

Comment: nice comment ,thanks